# Hive aggregation function that produces a map

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have the following hive table

ID, class,value

1, A, 0.3

1, B, 0.4

1, C, 0.5

2, B, 0.1

2, C, 0.2

I want to get

`ID, class:value`

`1, [A:0.3, B:0.4, C:0.5]`

`2, [B:0.1, C:0.2]`

---

I know that there is a `collect_set()` UDAF that produces a list of class or list of value, is there anyway to get a list of key:value pairs?

NOTE:
I guess I can use two `collect_set()` one for class column and one for value column but I am not sure if the lists will be in the same order.

Comment: There is a possible collect() in brickhouse an open source project with useful UDFs. http://brickhouseconfessions.wordpress.com/2013/02/21/lets-start-off-with-collect/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've used the UnionUDAF from the Brickhouse library to do something similar. You create a map from each pair, and then union them all together during the aggregation.

```
Add JAR brickhouse.jar;
create temporary function BH_union as 'brickhouse.udf.collect.UnionUDAF';

SELECT S.ID, BH_union(S.v_map) 
FROM (SELECT ID, map(class, value) as v_map from mytable) S
GROUP by S.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [custom Map/Reduce scripts](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Tutorial#Tutorial-CustomMap/ReduceScripts) and collect_list() (from Hive 0.13.0) to achieve the same.

Let me know if you need more help in this.